# For guest user, MS Graph API of Get Photo returns with 401 error

Tags: graph, botframework

We are building a Microsoft Teams App and in our app users use Graph api like

get users
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

get photo
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

For normal tenant users, every thing is fine, normal tenant users can get infos of users and photos of users by userIds.

However for guest users, "get users api" works well, but get photo api returns with the following error.

```
"error":{"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."
```

Does anyone knows the reason why this fails only for guest users and only for get photo api?

Comment: I just encountered the same problem, did you find a solution?